# Question about Integrability definition using Partitions of Unity

Tags: calculus

On page 65 of Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds, when defining the integral of an (potentially unbounded) $f$ on an (potentially unbounded) set $A$, there is a theorem, which states:

> If $A$ is Jordan-measurable and $f$ is bounded, then this definition
> of $\int_A f$ agrees with the old one.

Note that "this definition" refers to $\int_A f = \sum\limits_{\phi \in \Phi} \phi \cdot f$, where $\Phi$ is a partition of unity for some admissable open cover of $A$. The "old definition" refers to the integral defined on a bounded set and a bounded $f$ on this set, using $U(f,P)$ and $L(f,P)$.

**Question:**
$A$ is not stated to be bounded in this theorem. Is this just an omission, or does this follow from $A$ being Jordan-measurable?

Comment: Yes, page 56 says: A bounded set $C$ whose boundary has measure $0$ is called **Jordan-measurable**. So, it does not make sense to say that an unbounded set is Jordan-measurable (at least for now).

Comment: Thank you. I somehow missed that.